# spring mvc store data in server without using database

Tags: spring, facebook, caching, ehcache

i am working on a chatbot and need to save context of the previous conversation so that it can be sent to the next message. Now i m integrating it with facebook where facebook doesn't send context and need to store this context somewhere in a server. my client doesn't want to use DB. i tried sessions but technically i dont have a UI (facebook is the UI) . Next i tried ehcache but not able to retrieve data of previous webhook calls. Please let me know if any there is a method to store data and retrieve it latter without using DB.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not really a cache usage from what I can tell. That is you do not want to have entries disappear (eviction) and they do not get stale (expiration).

If that is correct, you will need to use the appropriate in-memory data structure so that you can store that information.
being more specific would require a bit more information about your system, the volume of data (per entry and max entries at once), etc ...